# Correlation between continuous independent variable and binary class dependent variable

Tags: pandas, statistics, correlation

Can someone please tell **if it's correct** to find `correlation` between a dependent variable that has `binary class(0 or 1)` and independent variables that have continuous values using pandas `df.corr()`.

I am getting correlation output if I do use it. But **I want to understand if it's statistically correct** to find pearson correlation(using df.corr()) between a binary categorical output and continuous input variables.

Comment: Why don't you start with the documentation for [df.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)?

Comment: i did go through. But I want to understand if it's statistically correct to find pearson coefficient in this case.

Comment: This might help: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea), [2](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-calculate-correlations-between-binary-variables), [3](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/point-biserial-correlation/).

Answer (score 0):

pearson correlation is for continues data if one is categorical and other is binary, you should use ANOVA to see the relation between variables [refrence](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-measure-the-correlation-between-continuous-and-categorical-variables)